# pointer to pointer as parameter of func

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
 void print_first_n_row(double **matrix, int n, int row) {
   int i,j;
   double x;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     for(j=0;j<row;j++){
       x=*(*(matrix+i)+j);
       printf("%lf",x); 
    }
    printf("\n");
  } 
}
```

I am not getting output with this func. What can be reason?

Comment: You use `row_size` but the parameter is `row`.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Don't write `*(*(matrix+i)+j)`.  Instead just write `matrix[i][j]`.  They're equivalent, but the latter is readable and the former is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting output"? No output, the wrong output, a crash...

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `%lf` in `printf`.  Just use `%f` for a `double` argument.

Comment: As for not getting any output, that suggests that one (or both) or `n` and `row` are `<= 0`.  Actually, if you're not even getting the newline, then `n <= 0`.

Comment: Show how you are calling the function and how you are preparing the arguments before the call.

Comment: @TomKarzes `%lf` is good for consistency and transparency with `scanf()` as `scanf()` ´s`%f` & `double` is an error.

Comment: @TomKarzes That´s why I asked how OP is calling the function.

Comment: @WeatherVane no output

Comment: In that case the loops do not iterate so `n` or `row` must be `<= 0`. But if "no output" also means "no newline" then the cause must be `n <= 0`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio That's true, although the Linux man page for `printf(3)` doesn't define the effect of following `l` with a floating-point specifier.  It only defines it when followed by an integer specifier, or character, or a few other types.  Are you sure it's defined by the C standard?

Comment: We need to more details.... Everything else is picking in the dark. Voted to close the question. I retract my vote if you provide more info.

Comment: @TomKarzes *"M.4 Second Edition 1 Major changes in the second edition (__STDC_VERSION__ 199901L) included: — %lf conversion specifier allowed in printf."* But it is unnecessary because `%f` is for `double`, and `float` operands for variadic functions are promoted to `double`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, you are right - the `l` has no effect: "*l(ell) Specifies that a following d,i,o,u,x, or X conversion specifier applies to along intorunsigned long intargument; that a following n conversion specifier applies toa pointer to along int argument; that a following c conversion specifier applies toawint_targument; that a followings conversion specifier applies to a pointer to awchar_targument; or **has no effect on a following a,A,e,E,f,F,g, or G conversion specifier**.*" -  But I just mentioned it because of the transparency to `scanf()`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, that's what I read, from the `printf` man page.  Weather Vane pointed out that `l` is allowed but ignored when applied to floating point formats, probably because people tried to use the same specifier they used for `scanf`.  But it wasn't always supported by `printf`, and it's unusual to see it in `printf` since it's just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In C, arrays are arranged in memory consecutively, row by row, referred to as *row major* for example, an array created like this:

```
int array[4][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};//4 rows of 3 columns
```

...is stored in memory as:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|
|row 1|row 2|row 3| row 4  |
```

So your function, *as it is written*, should be passing `n` as the number of rows to print in the second argument (as it does), but pass how many *columns* there are in the 3rd argument.

Change this:

```
void print_first_n_row(double **matrix, int n, int row)
```

to this:

```
void print_first_n_row(double **matrix, int n, int col)
```

I tested this change by creating `[4][3]` index accessible memory locations using allocated memory for: `double **matrix;` (4 pointers to double, each pointing to 3 double locations.) then populated each location with a series of numbers,and passed appropriate arguments:

```
int n = 4;
int col = 3;
void print_first_n_row(matrix, n, col);
```

I saw this:

[image]

When passed:

```
int n = 2;
int col = 3;
void print_first_n_row(matrix, n, col);
```

I saw this:
[image]

One other suggestion, as stated in comments:

This:

```
x = matrix[i][j];
```

Is much more readable than:

```
x=*(*(matrix+i)+j);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am not getting output."*

If you ain´t got output, either `n` or `row` (or even both) shall be `0` or smaller than `0` because if it would be different you shall get at least one output.

Check the values you pass as arguments to `n` and `row` in the calling function.

My personally assumption is that the newline form `printf("\n");` is getting printed, but you didn´t noticed the output of the line feed.